# Mongodb: choosing proper shard key and chunk size

Tags: mongodb, sharding

**I wonder if i should choose more precise shard key or have larger than 64MB chunks.**

Here is detailed description of my problem:

My collection "Posts" contain posts which belongs to "Projects" (each "Posts" document contains projectId field). All operations i do always with projectId = ... in query  condition, so at the first sight, the best shard key is projectId.
Very often i also use "createdDate" field  in query condition, but not always.

So i created collection Posts sharded by projectId key. But i realized, that some projects(5% of all projects) contains so many mentions, that total size of all documents with the same projectId will be larger than default chunk size (64MB).

Should i choose more specyfic shard key (eg compound key: projectId, createdDate) to avoid larger chunks than 64MB or should i let the chunks grow more than 64MB? I want to focus on fast read queries(especially aggregations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here on mongo google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/EO1LO0Un_vA